# Android XML vs code tablelayout differences

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I want to use code to generate a very large TableLayout.  XML works great but the file is getting huge and making changes would be tedious down the road.  The final layout will have a HorizontalScrollview on the right but my problem is best illustrated as follows.

The XML file is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Table 1"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Table 1"/></TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Table 2"/></TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Table 2"/></TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this outputs like this (sorry, can't post screenshot)

```
Table 1 Table 2
Table 1 Table 2
```

When I use code this this

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TableLayout table1 = new TableLayout(this);
table1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
for (int x = 0;x < 2;x++) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setText("Table 1");
    row.addView(tv);
    table1.addView(row);
}
TableLayout table2 = new TableLayout(this);
table2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
for (int x = 0;x < 2;x++) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setText("Table 2");
    row.addView(tv);
    table2.addView(row);
}
ll.addView(table1);
ll.addView(table2);
setContentView(ll);
```

it shows output like

```
Table 1
Table 1
```

I lose the second tablelayout. How can I change the code style to view that second tablelayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out why the second table doesn't work in code but I was able to fix my problem by

1. Setting up the LinearLayout and the TableLayouts in XML.
2. Then referencing the TableLayouts and adding the TableRows in    code.